# How to project GeoTIFF to specified area extent?

Tags: python, gdal, matplotlib-basemap, rasterio

I am trying to display GeoTIFF file in specified area. What I want to do is project multiband GeoTIFF file to specified area.

My GeoTIFF is satellite image containing 3 bands over area of Europe. I want to project it to area of Central Europe (extent defined by lat/lot). I have been trying to solve this using rasterio but I've been unlucky so far. This is what I get after executing:

```
import georaster
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

#define path to geotiff
file = "/home/lubomir/Desktop/Sentinel3_OLCI/RGB/OLCI_201812140859_Natural_Color.tif"

m = Basemap(epsg=3395,llcrnrlat=45,urcrnrlat=55,\
            llcrnrlon=5,urcrnrlon=25,lat_ts=15,resolution='f')

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5, color='g')
m.fillcontinents(color='beige')
m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5, color='m')

#load GeoTIFF multiband file
image = georaster.MultiBandRaster(file)

plt.imshow(image.r, extent=image.extent, zorder=10)
plt.savefig('test.tiff')
plt.show()
```

[without_geotiff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka6S7.png)

As you can see, generated image does not contain my GeoTIF. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you share your tiff file?

Comment: Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yttdtjawitoxrsv/OLCI_201812140859_Natural_Color.tif?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make use of the Basemap's projection, you must use

```
m.imshow(image.r, extent=image.extent, zorder=10)
```

in place of

```
plt.imshow(image.r, extent=image.extent, zorder=10)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The projection does not seem to be correct. The image is placed inside basemap but with wrong coordinates.

This is how my generated map looks like: https://upx.cz/Kt7
This is how it should look like (generated with QGIS): https://upx.cz/Kto

Do not consider the color of image, difference is cause by reading 1 band only in my code.

Comment: @LubomirFranko: Try `m.imshow(image.r, extent=image.extent, zorder=10 , origin='upper')`